# Compress images in smartest way

Tags: c#-4.0, image-processing, .net-4.0, compression

I have many images in the source folder, which are 10 MB each. I need to two operation on that image:

1. To compress that image and place it on destination folder 1
2. To create a thumbnail and place it on destination folder 2

As there are large number of images and they all are of huge size, can you guide me the fastest way to achieve this which consume less memory.

Comment: Do you need help with writing code or just need code?

Comment: I am seeking an idea to work on.. I don't want to trouble others to write code for me :-) just seeking a good advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

The http://imageresizing.net/ library does very memory-efficient image resizing - it's designed for server-side use, so naturally it is quite fast and designed for minimal memory use.

It's also simple to use.

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(sourceFile,destFile, new ResizeSettings("format=jpg;quality=90"));


ImageBuilder.Current.Build(sourceFile,destFile, new ResizeSettings("maxwidth=100;maxheight=100;format=jpg"));
```

There are 50+ different options - so pretty much any kind of automatic cropping, padding, seam carving, rotation, flipping, watermarking, etc. is possible.

I'm also working on a plugin which uses WIC for simple resize operations, which might give you a 2x speed boost. Let me know if you're interested in beta-testing it.

Comment: This indeed is a good solution but my client is not agree to have any third party control.

Comment: Well, the software is open-source, so you can look at the source code to get ideas of how to do it. Also, you should read http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/